# Is the verb "jimmy" related to "Jim Crow"?

Tags: american-english, offensive-language

The verb "jimmy" is more often used in American English than other dialects, and the main thing you "jimmy" is a crow bar.

Is the verb "jimmy" derived from the American English phrase "Jim Crow", which is rhyming slang for "negro"?

Comment: I’d say the main thing you jimmy is a **door**. The main thing you jimmy _with_ is a crowbar.

Comment: When I glanced at the title (and missed "verb"), I thought this was going to be about the chocolate sprinkles.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor which would be regarded as an offensive useage of the word, right?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I grew up in New England, and always heard chocolate sprinkles called "jimmies", but had never heard of it as an offensive term until a few years ago.  The impression I've had is that the offensive connection is more urban legend than anything else.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The suggestion made me laugh, so I had to check...and the answer is that I couldn't find any evidence that the verbal sense of 'jimmy', 'to use a crowbar', came from "Jumping Jim Crow" (or "Jump Jim Crow"), the title of the song that in part inspired a minstrel show that itself came to represent systemic discrimination.

The minstrel show was supposedly inspired by Thomas D. Rice's observation of

> a black stableman named Jim Crow who was dressed in ragged clothes. The man had a crooked leg and deformed shoulder.  While he worked, the man performed a song and dance called ‘Jumping Jim Crow’.... Rice bought Jim's clothes and learned his song and dance.

(From [**Blackface! Origins of Jump Jim Crow**](http://black-face.com/jim-crow.htm), retrieved 17 Sept 2015.)

The song perhaps did not originate with Rice or his sponsor, the unnamed "stableman"; rather it might have come from a slave folk song rooted in African

> ...folk tales of trickster animals, including birds, such as crows and buzzards who seem foolish, but who always manage to get what they want through cleverness and luck. In the Yoruba culture of West Africa, he is a crow named "Jim." The slave trade brought these folk tales to America and "Jim Crow" was a favorite.

(op. cit.)

After a somewhat cursory search, I was unable to find corroboration for the account at **Blackface!** other than an equally unsourced glancing mention:

> Some time around 1830, Rice learned a popular African-American song-and-dance routine, based on the myth of the trickster figure, an escaped slave named Jim Crow.

(From ["The Legacy of Blackface: Artists Take On Roots of Racist Performance Tradition"](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=1919122), June 03, 2004, retrieved 17 Sept 2015.)

Particularly, I was unable to find corroboration of the supposed source in Yoruba folk tales about a trickster figure named "Jim Crow". The principal animal trickster figure in Yoruba folk tales is a tortoise. My inability to find verifiable corroboration with a cursory search, however, does not necessarily mean the account at **Blackface!** is untrue or inaccurate.

Instead of corroboration, I did turn up a more scholarly account casting rather thorough doubt upon the story about Rice's inspiration for the minstrelsy. ["In Search of Jim Crow: Why Postmodern Minstrelsy Studies Matter"](http://www.robertchristgau.com/xg/music/minstrel-bel.php), by Robert Christgau ("Dean of American Rock Critics"), published by *The Believer* in 2004, tellingly reviews several other investigations into the origins of the song.

Christgau, saliently, cites musicologist Charles Hamm's analysis of the song:

> Hamm acknowledges that Rice "may have been telling the truth" before making what ought to be an obvious point: "It is equally likely that the story of the tune's origin was invented to give authenticity to a white man's portrayal of a black." Hamm believes Rice needed the help. He can discern no African elements in "Jim Crow," which suggested "both an Irish folk tune and an English stage song," ....

(Retrieved from ["In Search of Jim Crow: Why Postmodern Minstrelsy Studies Matter"](http://www.robertchristgau.com/xg/music/minstrel-bel.php) 17 Sept 2015.)

---

For **jemmy, n.**, I find this:

> 6. A crowbar used by burglars, generally made in sections screwing together.
>
> 1811   Lexicon Balatronicum   *Jemmy*, a *crow*..much used by house~breakers. Sometimes called Jemmy Rock.

["jemmy, n.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/101038 (accessed September 17, 2015). Emphasis mine. Note that, as pointed out by Sven in the comments, the spelling "Rock" in "Jemmy Rock" is an editorial error in the OED: the text of the 1811 [**Lexicon Balatronicum**](https://books.google.com/books?id=iDsJAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) shows "Rook", which is a type of Eurasian crow "with a bare face and a raucous voice".]

The noun and verb **jimmy** is from a dialectical and colloquial pronunciation of **jemmy**. The first textual evidence in the OED showing a verbal sense for 'jimmy' is 1893.

For **Jim Crow..., n.**, this:

> 1.
>
> a. The name of an early 19th-century plantation song of the American South; (also) a stage presentation of a song and dance first performed by Thomas D. Rice (1808–60) and subsequently by other actors dressed as blackface minstrels.

and also this:

> 2. An implement for bending or straightening iron rails by the pressure of a screw.
>
> 1875   in E. H. Knight Pract. Dict. Mech.

["Jim Crow | Jim-crow | jim crow, n.1". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/101312?rskey=gckEq3&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed September 17, 2015).]

Plus this from Collins:

> jim crow ... n (often capitals)
>
> ...
>
> 3. (Tools) an implement for bending iron bars or rails
> 4. (Tools) a crowbar fitted with a claw
>
> [C19: from Jim Crow, name of song used as the basis of an act by Thomas Rice (1808-60), American entertainer]

[Crow, Jim. (n.d.) Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged. (1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003). Retrieved September 17 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Crow%2c+Jim].

Comment: Hi, JEL. In your quote from _ Lexicon Balatronicum_, the word _Rock_ in the sentence "Sometimes called Jemmy Rock" should be _Rook_ (according to one source I've consulted). It certainly makes sense, since a rook is a [European] crow.

Comment: It appears in J.E. Lighter, _Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang_, volume 2. But I just found a copy of the original [_Lexicon Balatronicum_](https://books.google.com/books?id=iDsJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PT110&dq=%22Sometimes+called+Jemmy+Rook.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDEQ6AEwA2oVChMIvI2Ly9D-xwIVgkGICh2Afwg_#v=onepage&q=%22Sometimes%20called%20Jemmy%20Rook.%22&f=false) (1811), and it does indeed have _Rook_.

Comment: @SvenYargs, thanks, that's interesting. The spellings of 'rook' were many and various at that time. Place names particularly showed the 'Rock-' form. I took a look at the Balatronicum, however, and your source was correct; the answer is edited to reflect your discovery.

Answer (score 19):

According to Etymonline *Jimmy* is an expression first used in 1848 to refer to a crow bar, that was before [Jim Crow Laws](http://www.crf-usa.org/black-history-month/a-brief-history-of-jim-crow) (1875) were implemented. Its origin appears to be from a variant of the proper name "James".

[Jimmy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=jimmy):

> - "burglar's crowbar," 1848, variant of jemmy, name for a type of crowbar much used by burglars, special use of Jemmy, familiar form of proper name James.

As for the term ***[Crow](http://www.snopes.com/language/offense/crowbar.asp)***:

> - The use of the word 'crow' to describe an iron bar, usually with one end slightly bent and sharpened, is documented in English as far back as the year 1400. The device was so named because its splayed end resembled a crow's beak or foot; by the mid-18th century it was known as a 'crow bar,' and by the mid-19th century the two words had been joined to form 'crow-bar' and then finally 'crowbar.'
> - ***The use of the word 'crow' as a slang or pejorative reference to blacks didn't occur until three centuries later, however, and the term 'Jim Crow' not until another century after that***. Blacks were first called 'crows' in the 1730s, and the popularization of that term was almost certainly the progenitor of the 'Jim Crow' character created a hundred years later:
> - The term likely originated with a song introduced by blackface minstrel Thomas D. Rice about 1828. "Jim Crow," sung and danced by Rice in the United States and England, has as its introduction:
>
>   - *Come, listen all you gals and boys*,
>       *I'se just from Tucky hoe*;
>       *I'm goin' to sing a little song*;
>       ***My name's Jim Crow***.
> - The chorus ran:
>
>   - *Ebery time I wheel about I jump Jim Crow*.
>       *Wheel about and turn about and do jis so*,
>       *And ebery time I wheel about I jump Jim Crow*.
> - Rice is said to have patterned his song and dance on that of an old Kentucky field hand he had observed. His routine became so familiar that a few years later an antislavery book was titled *The History of Jim Crow*, ***and it is from such uses of Jim Crow to signify "Negro" that the discriminatory laws and practices take their name, though the first such laws were not enacted until 1875***.
> - Although 'crowbar' and 'Jim Crow' share a common root, neither term was derived from or references the other. ***Crowbars are simply tools, not linguistic remnants of a racist heritage***.

(www.snopes.com/language)

Note that proper names have often been used to refer to different contexts.

[Jack](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=jack&allowed_in_frame=0) for instance:

> - late 14c., jakke "a mechanical device," from the masc. name Jack. The proper name was used in Middle English for "any common fellow" (mid-14c.), and thereafter extended to various appliances replacing servants.

Comment: hard to argue with "detailed, intelligent answers"

Comment: _"The use of the word 'crow' to describe an iron bar, usually with one end slightly bent and sharpened, is documented in English as far back as the year 1400..."_  Possibly related is "hawk" in Hamlet's "When the wind is southerly I know a hawk from a handsaw," according to a 19th-century annotated Shakespeare that I have at home and don't have handy right now.

Answer (score 0):

A *[jimmy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jimmy)* is a crowbar:-

> A short crowbar with curved ends. [American Heritage Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]

so you *jimmy* things with a jimmy (in British English *[jemmy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jemmy)* is more common). The name is derived from the name *James*.

*[Jim Crow](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Jim+Crow)*:-

> The systematic practice of discriminating against and segregating
>   black people, especially as practiced in the American South from the
>   end of Reconstruction to the mid-1900s. [American Heritage Dictionary via the Free Dictionary]

is, according to that source,

> From obsolete Jim Crow, derogatory name for a black person,
>   ultimately from the title of a 19th-century minstrel song.

so, the answer is, no it isn't.

Comment: You may be right but there is a flaw (or something missing) in your line of reasoning. It is true that 'Jimmy' the name comes from the name 'James' but what does that have to do with the name of a crowbar? (Or the word 'jemmy' in UK English)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, I can't say that I know why _James_ (Jimmy or Jemmy) came to be a crowbar. Names are often used like this in underworld slang;  for example, _[Peter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peter)_ to mean a safe.

Comment: The etymology info from the first source is the somewhat uncertain statement "Probably from the name Jimmy, nickname for James."